# ZBarScannerView set camera size

Tags: android, camera, zbar

I am using ZBAR library to implement barcode scanning in my application. In ZBarScannerView, the view takes full width and height of screen to display camera. I have two barcodes placed one below another. While trying to scan the first barcode, sometimes it scans the second barcode and vice-versa. To solve this issue I am trying to set the size of the ZBarScannerView. But when I decrease the height of the view the width of the camera decreases as shown below.

[image]

Here is my code

```
private ZBarScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.scanner_height));
    mScannerView.setLayoutParams(params);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
}
```

Can anyone help me to set the size of the ZBarScannerView. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?